# Basic jquery mouseover animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi how may I make a simple mouse over animation to this logo? 
What I want is the id logo may come down 300px and inside I will put my links as navigation

```
<body>
<div class="content">
    <div id="logo"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/45/Google-Wallet-logo.svg/283px-Google-Wallet-logo.svg.png" alt="" /></div>
    <h1 class="title">Hello Moto</h1>
</div>
</body>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hzbRb/)

Comment: here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/hzbRb/

Comment: This is not the right site for this kind of questions. Try on your own and if you encounter a problem we're here to help. [35 jQuery Animation Tutorials](http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-animation-tutorials/)

Comment: You want it to just move 300px down from where it is or grow 300px on the bottom?

Comment: There are tons of answers on this type of question

Comment: The problem is I can only play with javascript not a create from nothing. So there will be here many people to help I thing.

Comment: if someone show me an article or write a single line of code i will be glad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**modify this CSS**

```
#logo {
    background: #f8b133;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    max-height: 500px !important; // this is critical!!
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#logo").on('mouseover', function () {
    $("#logo").animate({
        opacity: 0.95,
        height: "+=300"
    }, 250, function () {
        // Animation complete.
        // Show Navigation
    });
});
$("#logo").on('mouseleave',function () {
    // Hide Navigation
    $("#logo").animate({
        opacity: 1,
        height : "-=300"
    }, 250, function() {
    });
 });
```

I gave it a little opacity so your navigations might show up a bit better and you'll notice I use the `.one()` delegation so it doesn't continue to move down every time you mouseover.
**AFTER EDIT** Animations will run a bit faster now and you'll have the ability to hover and leave as many times as is needed rather than being limited to once, as long as you change the CSS.

[<kbd>working jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/hzbRb/5/)

Comment: this is also very good I just write height: "+=300" instead of margintop and it worked perfectly! but if I mouse out can it go back to 200px again?

Comment: Sure! Let me update the fiddle for you. There you go, see if you like that.

Answer (score 1):

Use mouseenter and leave

A working example Fiddle where I move the text around on hover: http://jsfiddle.net/hzbRb/1/

```
 $('#logo').mouseenter(function(){
     $('.content > h1').css('marginTop','30px')
 }).mouseleave(function(){
     $('.content > h1').css('marginTop','0px') 
 });
```

Comment: this worked perfectly! thanks! I will only look a way to make it with ease and smooth...